# android: How to change ListViewItem Background on runtime? (Not for selection)

Tags: android, listview

In my android app, I need to change the Background color of each Item of my ListView   seperately.
I found no examples or helpful documentation. The background should change if the value of a double is 0. I set the ListView Property:  `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"`  and used following code:
(All of it functions, only the background doesn't change!)  How can I solve this problem?

```
public void onClickButtonOKStand (View view) {
        EditAusgabe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        if (EditAusgabe.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
            Toast T = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Eingabe ungültig! Geben Sie einen Betrag ein", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            T.show();
            return;
        }
        if (EditAusgabe.getText().toString() == ".") {
            Toast T = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Eingabe ungültig! Geben Sie einen Betrag ein", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            T.show();
            return;         
        }

        Z = Double.parseDouble(EditAusgabe.getText().toString());

        if (VArt == "Down") {
            if (VStand >= Z) {
                VStand = VStand - Z;
                if (VStand <= 0.39) {
                    Toast T = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ihr Guthaben ist aufgebraucht!", Toast.LENGTH_strong textLONG);
                    T.show();
                    VStand = 0.00;

****************** The next line is my problem: ******************************

StartListe.getChildAt(Position).setBackgroundColor(color.holo_red_light);
                }
            }
            else if (VStand < Z) {
                Toast T = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vorgang nicht möglich! Ihr Konto liegt bei " + FORMAT.format(VStand) + " €.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                T.show();
                EditAusgabe.setText("");
                return;
            } 
        }

        if (VArt == "Up") {
            VStand = VStand + Z;
        }

        Stand.set(Position, FORMAT.format(VStand));
        Liste.set(Position, (VName + "               " + FORMAT.format(VStand) + " € / " + FORMAT.format(VWert) + " €"));
        ListeAktualisieren();
    }

    public void ListeAktualisieren () {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ausgabenkontrolle);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ListenAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Liste);
        StartListe = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        StartListe.setAdapter(ListenAdapter);
        StartListe.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> ListenAdapter, View view, int i, long ID) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Item = view;
                Position = ListenAdapter.getPositionForView(view);
                VName = Namen.get(Position);
                VArt = Arten.get(Position);
                VWert = Double.parseDouble(Werte.get(Position).toString());
                VStand = Double.parseDouble(Stand.get(Position).toString());
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_stand);
                if (VArt == "Down") {
                    if (VStand == 0) {
                    Toast T = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ihr Guthaben ist aufgebraucht!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    T.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(StartListe);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to change the background color in response to a click is to apply the change to the incoming View given to you in your onClickListener implementation. You seem to be messing about with setContentViews, etc. which isn't the way to go. SetContentView sets your overall layout, and there's rarely a reason to call it more than once in an Activity.

Comment: The color doesn't change when clicked on the item/view. It changes only then, when 
1. clicked on a button of another page ( I have 3 Pages) and
2. the controlled double (VStand) then has the value 0.
I used setContentView to switch between the 3 Pages/XML-files.
in onItemClick I defined Position as the Position of the clicked view, and said in the void above (onclickButtonOKStand):
set the backgoundcolor of the child of the List (which means the item in the ListView???) on position "Position" to red. am I wrong there? is there an aspect I missed?